# Phonegap - Android - Your device is not compatible with this version

Tags: android, cordova

I have generate and  .apk using phonegap build  and I'm having problem while trying to install it using a "Lg Optimus 3D" with Android version v.2.2.2.  Here is the config.xml that I am using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <widget xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
        xmlns:gap = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
        id        = "com.xxxxxxx.jjjjjjjjjjjjjj"
        version   = "1.0.0">

    <!-- versionCode is optional and Android only -->

    <name>THE NAME</name>

    <description>
        THE DESCRIPTION
    </description>

    <author email="XXX...@gmail.com">
        XXXXXXX 
    </author>

    <icon src="icon.png" width="72" height="72" />

    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/geolocation"/>
    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/network"/>
</widget>
```

I have not had any problems with any devices till now... what is happening with that mobile phone? what could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation here http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/2.9.0/configuring_preferences.md.htmlwe preferences in config.xml should look like this

```
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="8" />
```

in order to include Android 2.2